# Issue In Datetime Error in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have textbox i am passing datetime values of the textbox to db.In which it throws error"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
string startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text + " 00:00:00").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + " 00:00:00");
string enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text + "23:59:59").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + "23:59:59");//Throws datetime error
MastersClient OpeningStock = new MastersClient();
DataSet ds = OpeningStock.GetOpeningStockReport(location, startdate, enddate);
GridOpenstk.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridOpenstk.DataBind();  


 <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" 
     onkeypress='return AcceptDateCharacters(event, "-");' 
     onblur="DateValidation(this)" onkeyup = "ValidateDate(this, event.keyCode)" 
     onkeydown = "return DateFormat(this, event.keyCode)" 
     runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What is the value of `txtToDate.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: The issue is related to space, as pointed out below in answer, but you might have a bigger problem, Do not use `String` for date, I believe you are trying to retrieve data through database, if your column in database is of `DateTime` then use `DateTime` type objects instead of strings. To get start date you can use `DateTime.Today` and for end date you can do `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)`.

Comment: @Habib `AddTicks(-1)`? This is little bit hardcore bro `:)` I think you wanna say `AddSeconds(-1)` instead.

Comment: @SonerGönül, lol, why not `AddTicks(-1)`, Its accurate to 10,000 of a millisecond :), but sure, `AddSeconds(-1)` would be fine as well :)

Comment: @Habib Oh crap, always forget to use how `AddTicks` method works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space before `"23:59:59"`

```
string enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text + "23:59:59").ToString("yyyy-
                                                     ^
```

Compared to the working code:

```
string startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text + " 00:00:00").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" + " 00:00:00");
                                                        ^
```

Be aware that `Convert.ToDateTime` uses the current culture, and therefore it may behave differently on another machine with other language settings. It is better to use `DateTime.Parse` to parse the text to a `DateTime`.